# Change Canonical Href with Add Query Strings for Blogger? and with JavaScript or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, blogger, canonical-link

My example current url like this in browser:

`https://world.blogspot.com/p/any-page.html?country=France&city=Paris`

---

canonical tag like this in page source by browser:

`<link href="https://world.blogspot.com/p/any-page.html" rel='canonical' />`

---

I want to change from "any-page.html" to "any-page.html?country=France&city=Paris" in canonical tag for SEO.

There is not available query strings or other details in current canonical tag. 
I tried many many methods. Everything is unsuccessful.

Anybody have any advice for this ?

I tried this method
Change from "any-page.html" to "any-page.html?country=France&city=Paris"

```
if(!document.getElementById('id2')) {
    var link = document.createElement('link');
    link.id = 'id2';
    link.rel = 'canonical';
    link.href = 'https://world.blogspot.com/p/any-page.html?country=France&city=Paris';
    document.head.appendChild(link);
}
```

And similar methods didn't work too

Comment: this blogspot url just for example. not mine blog

Answer (score 2):

Actually till now **there is no blogger tags** rendering full page location with parameters.

You can render a single parameter using `?view=foo`, you might separate parameter and value using a dash `-` like that: `?view=country-France`.

---

**Edit:**

You can override existed `<link rel='canonical'>` tag href using Javascript with `location.href` to get full page link with parameters:

```
var CanonicalTag = document.querySelector('link[rel="canonical"]');
CanonicalTag.href = location.href;
```

Comment: Thank you for interest. My purpose change canonical href with JavaScript or jQuery. I updated my question with add unsuccesful script.